# Using Gauss lemma to prove formula for Legendre Symbol

Tags: number-theory

Posted this earlier but wanted to rewrite this question in a better way since it wasent well recieved.

I want to show $(\frac{a}{p}) = (-1)^{\sum_{i=1}^{(p-1)/2}{ \lfloor\frac{2ia}{p} \rfloor}}$.

The sum over $1$ to $(p-1)/2$ and the $i*a$ made me think of using Gauss's Lemma:
[image]

In gauss's lemma you have the sequence $a,2a,...,\frac{p-1}{2}a$, you take mod p, and then count up the number of numbers that are greater than $p/2$. That becomes the exponent.

In my formula it looks like we are counting the number of times p goes into numbers in the sequence $a,2a,..,\frac{p-1}{2}a$. Mod 2 i guess these are equivalently but im not sure how to go about showing that. Or is there another way of proving this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is interesting to observe that your formulation is similar to [Eisenstein’s Lemma](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Eisenstein%27s_Lemma), but there are two differences: In Einsenstein’s Lemma, $a$ is assumed odd, and in the floor function $ia/p$ (instead of $2ia/p$) is considered. However, as your guessed, your assertion is equivalent to the Gauss’s Lemma.

**Theorem**. Let $p$ be an odd prime, and $a$ be an integer with $\gcd(a,p)=1$. Then $$\left(\frac a p\right)=(-1)^n=(-1)^{\sum_{i=1}^{\frac{p-1}2}\lfloor\frac{2ia}p\rfloor},$$ where $n$ and the Legendre symbol are as mentioned in the question.

*Proof*. One proves below the second equality. For $1\leq i \leq \frac{p-1}2$, $ia$ is not divisible by $p$. Applying the Division Algorithm, one can divide into two cases.

**Case** 1. $$ia=kp+r,\qquad 1\leq r<\frac p 2$$
$$\Rightarrow \lfloor\frac{2ia}p\rfloor=2k+\lfloor\frac{2r}p\rfloor=2k$$

**Case** 2. $$ia=kp+r,\qquad \frac p 2<r<p$$
$$\Rightarrow \lfloor\frac{2ia}p\rfloor=2k+\lfloor\frac{2r}p\rfloor=2k+1$$

It follows from the two cases that $$r>\frac p 2\Leftrightarrow \lfloor\frac{2ia}p\rfloor~{\rm is ~odd,}$$ hence the summation occurring in the exponent is congruent to $n$ mod $2$. QED